# is there a way and how, to make a ui in termanal with lua?

Tags: lua, terminal

i am just wondering if it's posable and also I will need a example to understand what I need to do for it?
i am needing it for a cross over between lua and the termanal to make a ui

Comment: You can install [dialog](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2807) and use it from Lua: `local name = io.popen'dialog --inputbox "Enter your name:" 8 40 2>&1':read'*a'`

Comment: i need to roll with out luarocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is https://github.com/luaposix/luaposix exists.

Actually, I had developed luancurses some time ago, but I've abandonned it in favour of luaposix: it works under latest lua releases (5.2, 5.3) and has ncurses bindings too.

And there are examples, including ncurses ones.

Comment: are there termanal commands i can run with ' os.execute() ' so i don't have to call any modules?